# How do I check the texts of New York State laws online?

Tags: new-york-state, legal-research

I want to read up the text of laws online. I am specifically interested in New York State laws. Is there a webpage where I can read up on the text of laws in New York State, or perhaps some other state in the USA?

Answer (score 2):

There's an FAQ on the Meta site for [Online Legal References](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/online-legal-references) which includes [New York Law](https://www.findlaw.com/state/new-york-law.html) from the FindLaw.com site, with the other states [here](https://www.findlaw.com/state.html).